# Código fonte aparecendo na aba source do devtools

Tags: react

Tô com um problema que envolve o código inteiro do site, quando abro o devtools e vou em source, lá dentro tem a pasta static e dentro dela tem outra pasta que se chama js. O código fonte todo está lá dentro, hooks, componentes... Como posso fazer pra que isso não aconteça? Lembrado que eu não mexi em nada do env ou webpack. Só criei a base com o create-react-app e comecei a desenvolver. Depois de pronto, eu não rodei o build, só passei os arquivos pra uma repo pv e depois mandei pro netlify fazer o resto, lá ele fez a build e tudo mais. Só que eu tô com esse problema. A aplicação é em reactjs.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Modifique seu **package.json**, deixe seu build dessa forma, após só buildar e rodar que já não vai aparecer mais o maplist no navegador.

```
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
```

Comment: O que significa buildar? É o nome de algum personagem de tokusatsu? Essa resposta não parece fazer sentido pois o comando `set` em ambiente Posix é usado para definir e determinar os valores do sistema. Poderia explicar o raciocínio por de trás desse script?